# Save Actions plug-in for JetBrains PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

There is a plug-in called "Save Actions" available for IntelliJ IDEA. Now I want to know if there is a plugin with the same functionality for PhpStorm? I want to add the this, final and PHPDoc declarations at the save Action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an open request](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/issues/18) to make Save Actions plug-in available for all IntelliJ platform based IDEs.

Developer [has shared](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/issues/18#issuecomment-237618647) an experimental version that should work with PhpStorm:

- [save-actions.zip](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/files/402183/save-actions.zip)

You can [install it manually from zip](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/installing-plugin-from-disk.html).

Comment: Thank you for that answer. @DanielPfeil I'd appreciate if you'd post on the github if it woks for you in PhpStorm.